# google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied but service account have the permission it needs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-tasks

I am currently using python GCP API  to create a cloud task queue. My codes are modified from the sample code and the logic is to check if the queue exists or not, if not create a new queue and put new task to that queue. so I use try-except and import `from google.api_core import exceptions` to handle the error. But the problem right now it keeps saying that my service account don't have permission cloud task. Here is the error.

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudtasks.tasks.create" for the resource "projects/xxxx/locations/us-central1" (or the resource may not exist).
```

here is my code.

```
@app.route('/train_model/<dataset_name>/<dataset_id>/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def train_model(dataset_name,dataset_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.form
        model = form.get('model_name')
        date = form.get('date')
        datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')
        timezone_date_time_obj = timezone.localize(datetime_object)
        data=[dataset_id,model]
        payload = str(data).encode()

        # Create a client.

        url = "https://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/create_csv"
        try:
            client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient.from_service_account_json(
                './xxxxx.json')

            url = "https://us-central1-xxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/create_csv"
            location = 'us-central1'
            project = 'xxxxx'
            queue = 'testing1'
            parent = client.location_path(project, location)
            task = {
                "http_request": {
                    'http_method': 'POST',
                    'url': url,
                    'body': payload
                }}
            # set schedule time
            timestamp = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
            timestamp.FromDatetime(timezone_date_time_obj)
            task['schedule_time'] = timestamp
            response = client.create_task(parent, task)

        except exceptions.FailedPrecondition:
            location = 'us-central1'
            project = 397901391776
            # Create a client.
            client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient.from_service_account_json(
               "./xxxx.json")
            parent = client.location_path(project, location)
            queue = {"name": 'x'}
            queue.update(name="projects/xxxxx/locations/us-west2/queues/" + queue #the name of the queue from try.)
            response = client.create_queue(parent, queue)
            parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)
            task = {
            "http_request": {
                'http_method': 'POST',
                'url': url,
                'body':payload
            }}
            # set schedule time
            timestamp = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
            timestamp.FromDatetime(timezone_date_time_obj)
            task['schedule_time'] = timestamp
            response = client.create_task(parent, task)

        print(response)
        return redirect('/datasetinfo/{}/{}/'.format(dataset_name,dataset_id))
```

the permission of my service account
[image: x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your scenario and I managed to get the same issue. The problem is not with the authentication but that the resource doesn't exist.

In order to get the resource path, instead of using the function `location_path` you should use `queue_path`. This way, the variable `parent` will contain the queue's name and the call `create_task` will be able to find the resource.

Finally, giving the role Editor to a service account may be too much, you should restrict the access to the minimum viable. If this code only needs to create tasks, you should create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role) with just the required permissions, `cloudtasks.tasks.create` in this case.

Comment: Is there any other reason this may occur? I have the same issue (SA is editor as well), the resource exists as another Cloud Run creates tasks with no issues. Both Cloud Runs use the queue_path, but one will fail with this same permissions error

Comment: @user1596707 The cause still remains the same, either the SA lacks the permission or the accessed resource doesn't exist. What could be happening is that either the SA being used is not the one you are expecting or the resource is not being accessed properly. My suggestion would be to add more logging to troubleshoot both aspects of the request. If you cannot find the reason on your end, I would suggest opening a [new question](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/stackexchange) with the `google-cloud-tasks` tag.